# Is This A Constant Sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $a≥1$ be any real number.Now define a sequence as below

> $a_n:=\sqrt[n]{[a^n]}$ (where $[x]$ is the integral part of $x$). If $a_n$ is a natural number for every sufficiently large natural number $n$ then prove that $a$ is a natural number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a^n = (I_n)^n + f_n,  I_n\in \Bbb Z,  0\leq f_n <1$$
$$(I_n/a)^n = 1- f_n/a^n$$
Now, $f_n/a^n$ converges to zero, hence $(I_n/a)^n$ converges to 1. This is only possible if $I_n = a$, else $(I_n/a)^n$ either diverges or converges to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

You get 
$$
a^n-1<[a^n]\le a^n
$$
so that
$$
a\sqrt[n]{1-\frac1{a^n}}<a_n\le a
$$
and the difference between upper and lower bound goes to zero. From that the rest follows.

Comment: I can not conclude plz add something more

Comment: What do you know about converging sequences of integers?

Comment: They may be eventually constant and the limit is that constant integral value

Comment: And this integral limit has to be $a$ by the limits of the bounds.